# A way to check a BufferedImage repaint()?

Tags: eclipse, if-statement, mouseevent, repaint

I'm working in Eclipse and I want to know if I can make an if statement that checks to see if the `BufferedImage` has been painted/drawn onto the frame. For some reason, it's not painting the correct image because clickable regions are appearing on that picture when they are not supposed to.

For example, when I click the region to go from 4>5 everything is good. When I click from 5 to go to 4 I end up at 6 because the 'regions' from 4 are appearing in 5 (The image should always be painted before the clickable regions are shown) before it's even being painted. I want to restrict this to check if the image has been painted onto the frame first.

I really don't want to use anything else besides what I have right now (so no new classes being implemented to do this task), I really just want a simple yet effective way to resolve this. Here is what I'm talking about:

```
...
MouseAdapter mouseHandler = new MouseAdapter()
      {
          public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
          {
            repaint();
             if(n==0)
            {
              if(e.getX()>=459 && e.getX()<491 && e.getY()>=111 && e.getY()<133
                 {
                     n = 4;
                 }
                 return;
            }
            if(n==5)
            {
                if(...)
                {
                    n = 4;
                }
                    return();
            }
            if(n==6)
            {
               if(...)
                {
                    n = 5;
                }

               if(...)
                {
                    n = 0;
                }

               if(...)
                {
                    n = 6;
                }
                    return();
        }
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution, I forgot to come back to this question and let you know. The problem was that the mouse was double clicking for some reason. You could almost say it was 'recursive'. I decided to move the mouseListener from inside the paintComponent to outside of it, and surely enough that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to give a little more information. The problem might lie in how you repaint, not whether it was painted. 
If you are running another thread as your main program, you might instead want to send the mouse events synchronously to that so that the main thread can process the mouse click and then repaint.

Another solution might be to override the repaint method and paint the buffered images there, but you may have done that.

Also, a little off topic, I noticed that you used for loops to determine if the mouse was clicked in a specific area.

You could shorten the code:

```
for(int i=459; i<491; i++){
    if(e.getX()==i){
        for(int j=111; j<133; j++){
            if(e.getY()==j){
                //action taken
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To:

```
if(e.getX()>=459 && e.getX()<491 && e.getY()>=111 && e.getY()<133{
    //action taken
}
```

This would take up less space in your code and less time checking every pixel.

Back to your question. 
I dont know of a function to tell if a buffered image has been painted. The ploblem that you are having though might of might not be in the code provided. Posting the rest of your code would be beneficial.

Comment: Agh, okay. If you're going to be on longer I can explain in depth. I', still having trouble with this. In the mean time I'm going to shorten my code.

Comment: I'll be on for a while more.

Comment: Okay, I shortened the code and everything is a lot more easier on my eyes. I've been using the mouse listener recently so I don't know much about syncing the events. To explain what's going on in the game is when I enter room 5, there is only one clickable region. That region should take me to room 4. What happens is that it shows the clickable regions in room 4 without painting it first. What happens with this is that I can now go to room 6 (which is only possible via 4) via room 5. EDIT: Sorry if this is confusing I have a simple diagram, would you like to see it?

Comment: Sure. A diagram would be helpful. I think I'm getting what you are saying. Are you saying that when you move to room five from room four, the image for going to room six remains when it should only show the region for going back to four? If thats the case, then the problem might be in the repaint. If you are not compleatly repainting everything, starting with painting the background color over the entire screen, "ghost" images can appear.

Comment: Well it's not that the image is staying there. It's that the clickable regions for another room are being permitted for the user to click, even when they aren't allowed to (if n = ...). But this is only happening for 5 > 4, no other rooms. Here's the pathway: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1jG1U.jpg

Comment: If it only happens when you try to go from five to four, what may be happening is an overlap for that particular case. Check each of your if statements carefully. Try changing: if(n==a number){...} if(n==another number){...} to: if(n==a number){...} else if(n==another number0{...}

Comment: Yeah, your right!  It is overlapping! Agghhh I can't get it to work!

Comment: Here are my findings (In the picture you are in room 5). http://i.imgur.com/cSXVAzC.jpg

Comment: Did you chage your "if" statements after the initial if to "else if" yet? From the look of the diagram, your program might check if n==5, set n to 4, then check to see if n==4. If you don't have "else if" after the first if statement, the program will continue checking each statement. I saw that you had return inside each if statement, but I would add "else if" statements anyway.